# tkinter Entry widget calling a function whenever a letter is entered

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-entry

I'm trying to build a program in which I will give a suggestion of a word entered already; like google search bar

So, Is there any way to get words from Entry widget before hitting enter.

my possible idea was:
binding all character to Widget and Function. But, it would be very complex.

So, Is there any other idea or possibility to do that.

Comment: assign Entry widget to a variable and trace that variable. Check this out for more info:https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/tracing-tkinter-variables-in-python/

Comment: Bind the `<Key>` event.

Comment: In the [ttkwidgets](https://pypi.org/project/ttkwidgets/) package there is an autocomplete module which provides an Entry and Combobox with autocompletion, maybe you can use one of them or look into the code.